# Gained access to private beta without committing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, private-beta, commitment

I was just able to access the new Joomla private beta, but I never committed to the proposal (though I did followed it).

Here's my [Area51 Profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/67019/joshua-dwire) showing I never committed, and here's my [Joomla Profile](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/194/joshua-dwire).

The steps I used to gain access were something like this. I can't remember exactly, and there are no other private betas to test the process on.

1. Visit the [private beta page](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/)
2. Click on the [meta.joomla](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/) link in the message/alert banner at the top. The meta and all of it's questions were visible without signing up.
3. Do something (can't remember exactly) to get to the signup page for the meta.
4. Switch to the login tab.
5. Log in with my existing Stack Exchange account.
6. Watch as I am redirected to the Joomla SE home page and can view everything.
7. ?????
8. Profit

I confirmed that I was able to vote and make comments, since I immediately received an association bonus. It was my understanding that private betas were only to be accessible by those who committed, but until this is fixed, everyone enjoy unauthorized access to private betas.

Oh, don't feel that I'm asking for my ill-gotten Joomla SE account to be deleted. I'd love to be the only participant in the private beta that didn't commit.

Comment: Yes, this is by design. We decided that is someone is interested in a site enough to go through area51 and click the link, they can participate.

Comment: @Oded That makes sense. I thought I searched, but now I'm seeing the answer in the related posts sidebar.